# Passing data object between XAML pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I haven't found any useful answer, or should I say "any answer" that how can I pass data objects between the pages in WP7?

PAGE1

```
IEnumerable<dictParts> Parts = LoadParts();
```

How can I pass `Parts` to PAGE2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [How to pass a value between Silverlight pages for WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637533/how-to-pass-a-value-between-silverlight-pages-for-wp7)

You have a couple of options:

- Serialize the data and pass it on the querystring of the Navigate() request.
- Store the data in a global variable that is accessible from both pages (like the MVVM pattern).

Comment: It can be done by using global variable

    public static class GlobalVariables
    {
       public static string my_string = "";
       public static int my_int = -1;
    }
    
Then you access the Global Variables class like this: GlobalVariables.variable_name e.g. `GlobalVariables.my_string`;

Ref: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/66396/573232.aspx

Comment: Be sure you are careful about memory leaking (i.e. - you may want to nullify the object when you go back from the page.)