# How to navigate data from page to page?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to display the longlistselector data in a new page when an item was selected.. im getting an error message System.Argument.Exception so plz help me to solve this issue..

**my selectedindex change code..**

```
private void OrganizationList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{                
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Organization_Details.xaml?selectedItem" +Organization.Name , UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Error:

[image]
In the navigated page, i'm jus using a text block to display my data..and the code is..

```
Organization org;//Class name with obj

public Organization_Details()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    org_name.Text = org.name;//textblock(org_name)-->needs to set the data from the b4 page..
}
```

[image]

Error in navigated page...

Comment: Follow this Page, might get your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016387/passing-data-object-between-xaml-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Organization_Details.xaml?selectedItem=" +Organization.Name , UriKind.Relative));
```

You have missed **"/"** at the begining of your url and **"="** after selectedItem

Comment: And he misses "=" after selectedItem.

Comment: Thanx guys..when i navigate to next page im getting another error.. plz help me...check the post again..

Comment: Maybe you should first look at a tutorial like http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Navigating-and-Passing-Data-between-XAML-Pages

Comment: Seriously, read something about it! Stack overflow is not a trial and error forum. One more resource: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620719/Windows-Phone-Page-Navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the value directly, so use the following function,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("selectedItem"))
            {
                //Get the value here
            }
     }
```

This would work fine for you!!